# Porting UICollectionView code from IOS 8/9 to IOS 10

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have started to port my app to IOS 10 and realize there is a major change in the UICollectionView behaviour to the point the collectionview images no longer show.

Through forums I could see what is new in UICollectionView but could not find an answer to the following question: is there a way to port old UICollectionView code working in previous iOS version without doing major change ?

Any pointers are much appreciated ...

Stephane

Comment: There really wasn't any significant collection view changes

Comment: Might be an autolayout change, you should see if your constraints are still working (if you use autolayout). Other than that, there weren't really any API changes that might cause this.

Comment: There have been some big changes, but nothing that should break any existing code. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/

Comment: Switching off Autolayout has made the problem apparent as the UICollectionView started to appear again.  As Dima pointed out there has been some constraints at play. As a side note, for anyone who is facing a similar situation, remember to backup your files before turning off Autolayout otherwise you lose all your constraints of all screens :) Thanks to all for the pointers and help!